Wordpress-Underscores-CSS unable to load CSS file correctly
I try to make a Website with Wordpress and use the Underscores - Theme.
I made a custom CSS file under /css/custom-css.css to style the most part of the website.
If i load the CSS by the funciton.php noting happen.
If i inspect the website on Firefox under the Style-Editor-tab i fine my css with a long and strange HTML code.
The third line is my function.php code, which i added to the existing UnderscoreS - Code to load the styles and scripts:
function hirsch_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'hirsch-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), _S_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css-style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/custom-css.css', array(), null, 'all');
    wp_style_add_data( 'hirsch-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'hirsch-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hirsch_scripts' );

The test code in my custom.css:
#home-title {
    background-color: blue !important;
    color: red;
}

A screenshot and the beginning of the HTML code that appears in the style-editor tab from the inspector (very long):
enter image description here
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de-CH">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <LINK href="./css/custom-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

I try to load it on several different ways. I'm not sure if the CSS doesn't get loaded at all or if the UnderscoreS - Theme tries to convert it in to a HTML (which would be indicated by the inspector). But i'm not used to the style-editor tab, so maybe i missinterpretate that.
Thanks a lot for any help.
Update:
I think i figured it out. "get_stylesheet_uri()" seems to direct up to .../style.css. i have to use "get_template_directory_uri()".

the css file is here but empty : https://wilder-hirsch-wittenbach.ch/wp-content/themes/hirsch/css/custom-css.css. is that intentional ?

Thanks for the reply. I deleted the contend and will work on the style.css till i have a working solution. I can set it back to the point, when i asked the Question.

I figured it out.
Actually "get_stylesheet_uri()" loads ./style.css, so the path directs to the file. I would need to go to a higher hierarchy or simply use "get_template_directory_uri()".
As far as i understood, it could be a problem if someone would make a child-theme but for me it workes fine :).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
